# MACRO_ENSURE_OUT_OF_SOURCE_BUILD stops make

Tags: cmake

Our project depends on ifm3d as a submodule. Compilation now fails with

```
CMake Error at dep/repo/dep/ifm3d/cmake/modules/MacroOutOfSourceBuild.cmake:10 (MESSAGE):
  Please build IFM3D out-of-source
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  dep/repo/dep/ifm3d/CMakeLists.txt:12 (macro_ensure_out_of_source_build)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/me/repo/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/me/repo/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

It seems the macro tries to persuade me to compile out of a specific folder. However, I have no idea how to fix this

https://github.com/lovepark/ifm3d/blob/master/cmake/modules/MacroOutOfSourceBuild.cmake

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a folder, the so called build directory, the name does not matter. Enter it, call `cmake <path to source directory>` and run make (or whatever you build tool you use).

Example, when you are in the root directory of your project.

```
makedir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```